# How to setup CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS flag in perl dbi for mysql connection

Tags: mysql, perl, stored-procedures

How to set CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS flag in perl dbi for mysql connection? I have to use a stored procedure with a select query at the end. I learned that to use this kind of procedure, I have to set CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS flag. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 3.0002_5, the driver ([DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3amysql)) supports multiple result sets and thus sets the option automatically. (The latest version is 4.022, so one would assume it's a stable feature.)

See the relevant [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3amysql#MULTIPLE_RESULT_SETS) for an example that shows how to fetch all the result sets.

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't have the permission to install the module and our current module is 2.9007. Is there a way to get around of this? Thanks.

Comment: If you can't use any code but your own, that just leaves writing your own.

Comment: Another alternative would be to not ask for permission.

Comment: Finally, another alternative is to get permission.

Comment: Developers in the real world have a lot of restrictions at least in the environment where I am. I tried the 3.0008 version but it doesn't work. Anyway, thanks. Finally, we changed the stored procedure not to use these select queries.

Comment: I never said otherwise. I even gave you three options. I wasn't about to write code you couldn't use, if that's what you were expecting.

Comment: Easy, easy. :) I wasn't blaming you. How can I blame you with "thanks" literarily in every post? :) It's just if you were in my shoes you would be frustrating with the inaccuracy of the document as well. Actually, I googled and read the document in your answer before I posted this question.

Comment: You could try getting in touch with the author and asked if it's suppose to work in 3.0008.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thanks. However, I probably won't do that.